# create new site subsite in wordpress multisite by subscriber user instead of network admin

Tags: multisite

How to create new site subwebsite in wordpress multisite by subscriber user instead of  main admin.

I want registered user can create one sub domain instead of  network admin.

i have search my there is no option to add new sub-site by sub users.

is there any option or custom code  or any free plugin please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **/wp-admin/network/settings.php** as a *Super Admin* and where it says *"Allow new registrations"* set it to one of these:

- *"Logged in users may register new sites"* (no new users can register)
- *"Both sites and user accounts can be registered"* (new users can register)

Both these settings allow logged in users to create new sites by clicking on *"My Sites"* and then *"Add new"*, which points them to **/wp-signup.php**.

Comment: I have gone through  your given instructions

Go to /wp-admin/network/settings.php as a Super Admin and where it says "Allow new registrations" set it to one of these:
"Both sites and user accounts can be registered" (new users can register)
but not able to create sub domain by subscriber user
 do you have any other solution.
after follow your given instruction not able to see "add new site"  for subscriber user.

one profile and dashboard option is there for  subscriber user.
could you please check again  and let me know

Comment: @user3811650 Deactivate all plugins and switch to a default theme. Then try again. Any plugin or theme could be changing the permissions of users.

Comment: I have gone through deactivate all plugin from main website.
right now  after login i am able to see only dashboard and profile.
how i give  permission to sub user for add post or page.
at time of create sub domain default content should copy from main website to sub domain.

Do you have any custom code for that because using these setting it is not working at my end.

I want when user login ,user can create only one own sub domain site
like user is ram and main site is test.com
so after login sub user can create ram.test.com

Comment: @user3811650 You are mentioning a lot of things and not explaining them well enough. Lets focus on creating sites by users. Choose one of the settings I mentioned and then log in as a subscriber user and visit example.com/wp-signup.php where example.com is your main site. Let me know what happens when you visit this page.

Comment: Thanks @nikolay now it is working  for after login from subscriber user.
 after login from registered user when i browse example.com/wp-signup.php 
  then front end we can see three field  for create site ,fields are

If you’re not going to use a great site domain, leave it for a new user. Now have at it!

Site Domain:
Site Title:
Privacy ->Allow search engines to index this site.

it is possible to admin end ,i means after login from subscriber user can create website from admin side

Comment: @user3811650 I am happy it worked. I think you also asked a question in this last comment, but your English is bad, and I did not understand even after reading it twice.

Comment: Thanks @nikolay ,My question is for last comment is like 
After login from subscriber user ,user can create website from front end using example.com/wp-signup.php 
and it is front end.
but i want subscriber user can create new website from admin side not from front end.

Comment: @user3811650 Ah, I understand now. Well, I know how you can do it, but I do not recommend it. To be able to create sites on the back end in the network admin area, a user needs to have these two capabilities: manage_network and create_sites. You can give these two capabilities to the subscriber role with a plugin called "User Role Editor". I tried it and it worked. But giving the manage_network capability is risky. I am not sure what else will they be able to do with it.